# Eclipse / Rename parameters in a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to change the naming conventions of parameters. Until now we've used a "p"-prefix, but I think it isn't necessary and I would like to get rid of the prefix and also change the uppercase character which follows the "p" to a lowercase. Is this somehow possible to do in the whole project in "one run"?

Comment: I faced the same problem and found no easy solution. Good luck and maybe I learn something from other answerers :)

Comment: Hopefully there's a way, otherwise I'm not sure if I will probably stick to the "ugly" naming convention :-(

Comment: I stuck to it, yes :) You may possibly consider a blanket regexp-replace. There probably aren't many other strings in the project that satisfy `\bp[A-Z]\w*`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of one parameter in the whole project in Eclipse do the following:

Click on the parameter.

press [alt] + [shift] + [R].

enter the new name.

press enter to accept the new name, it will change over the whole project. This also works on class names, methods etc.

I'm sorry, but this way you have to do this for all parameters again.

Comment: Yes, I know, but hmm, that's not what I hoped for ;-)

Comment: Maybe there is an other way. But whenever to do this with pattern matching you have to force the problem of "false positive" matching ruin your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use File / Search. You can do a find and replace in all the files in the workspace. This accepts regular expressions as well.